# How to use Rows.Count function if there are blank cells in between data

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code that adds in data from my excel sheet if the item the user selects is equal to the range in J. This works perfectly if the range in J is filled in with all the data, but how do I get the row to still count all the way through the last filled cell if there are blanks in between? I attached a picture to show what I mean.

[image].

I would want to count the rows all the way down to the last "Gold". Right now it only counts to the second.

```
Private Sub cboName_Click() 'only get values that are assigned
    Dim j As Integer, k As Integer, i As Integer
    Me.lstProvider.Clear
    i = 0
    Worksheets("Biopsy Log").Select
    For j = 1 To Range("J2", Range("J1").End(xlDown)).Rows.count 
        If Range("J2", Range("J2").End(xlDown)).Cells(j) = Me.cboName.Value Then 
            If Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Cells(j) = "Assigned" Then 
            With Me.lstProvider
                .AddItem
                For k = 0 To 5
                    .List(i, k) = Range("A" & j + 1).Offset(0, k) 
                Next
            End With
            i = i + 1 
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `For j = 1 To Range("J2", Range("J1").End(xlDown)).Rows.count` use `Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` (assuming GOLD is in column J).  The code does the opposite of `xlDown`.  It goes down to the last row of the sheet (`Rows.count`) and moves up until it find the first non-blank cell.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `xlDown`, try to use `xlUp` from the bottom to get the last row for correct range:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Worksheets("Biopsy Log")

For j = 1 To sht.Range("J" & sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If sht.Range(...)
```

Qualifying `Range` calls with an explicit `Worksheet` object makes your code more robust.

Comment: What is sht? What should it be referring to or dimmed as?

Comment: @kd99 your code is implicitly referring to `ActiveSheet` everywhere you use `Range` without a qualifier. `Dim sht As Worksheet`, and then `Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Biopsy Log")`, and then use it to explicitly qualify every `Worksheet` member call. So you do `sht.Range(...)` instead of just `Range(...)`, which is fragile code. Bonus, you get to remove the `Worksheet.Select` call.